# How to control an Angular Material Sidenav programmatically

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'd like to be able to toggle a sidenav from the component.ts without having to press a button on the html.

I have:

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
        <mat-sidenav  #roadmapConcept mode="overlay" style="width:60vw;" position="end" fixedTopGap="56">   
</mat-sidenav>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

In the component I've tried:

```
roadmapConcept.toggle();
```

However I get the error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'roadmapConcept.toggle')
```

What would be the appropriate way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: How did you declare roadmapConcept in the component?

Comment: That's been my problem - not sure how! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template reference variable is often a reference to a DOM element within a template.

In this `#roadmapConcept` is a Template reference variable.
So its seems you have not declare #roadmapConcept in your component that why it show undefined.

We can access native DOM elements that have a template reference variable. We can access the input itself with `ViewChild` like this:

```
@ViewChild('roadmapConcept') roadmapConcept: ElementRef;
```

and then use in your class file:  `roadmapConcept.toggle();`

You can look out this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nrv99d) may this helps you!

Comment: Great, that worked! Small update for Angular 8:
@ViewChild('roadmapConcept',{static:false}) roadmapConcept: ElementRef;